# How to get Sandcastle to include inherited properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, chm, sandcastle

I have 2 POCO classes for my view model:

```
public class BaseView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class FullView : BaseView
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate a CHM help file using Sandcastle (2014.5.31.0) both are included but the FullView only shows it's 2 properties.

How can I get it to include the BaseView properties that it is inheriting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the Sandcastle project > Properties > Visibility > Inherited Base Class Members

[image: sandcastle screenshot]

Comment: It may be because I am using the API Filter to limit it to only stuff we want to expose

Comment: Nope, I removed the API Filter and it still is only showing the FullView properties

Comment: Hang on, it is now showing them all! Must be something to do with the API Filter. I'll tinker some more

Comment: @Shevek I'm glad it worked :) If you needed to do any extra steps, let me know and I'll add them to the answer to make it easier for future readers.

Comment: All I did was remove the API filter and it worked! I then re-applied the API filter, and it still worked... <shrug>