# Sandcastle hide that your class inherits an other class in the signature ("class signature")

Tags: c#, sandcastle

I am documenting my API and I want to hide that one of my classes inherits a base class. example `public class Foo:FooBaseClass`.
This is the current display in my html documentation. However I want to show it this way `public class Foo`. I managed to hide the inherited members, fields, methods etc from the documentation but I can't hide that my class inherits an other class... Is it possible?

Comment: There's a config option to turn off inheritance chain

Comment: @JohnPeters can you tell me where exactly it is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388192/how-to-get-sandcastle-to-include-inherited-properties